# Compare 2 list and reproduce dynamically like two matrix in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a little problem:
Compare 2 lists and reproduce dynamically like two linear matrix in Tkinter (two rows of labels, generated dynamically in Tkinter) but when the program detects a difference in one of two lists, it changes the color of the background of wrong number label. Example; I will write ASCII-art where put number and right side in parenthesis the bg-color. colors: grey & red-g&r
generated: |1(g)|2(g)|3(g)|  <=the generated array ever in grey.
input:     |1(g)|9(r)|3(g)|  <=The input array be compared and do this.

For run the program download and install in virtualenv the requirements.txt, and it's run in Python3.5.

And it is the snippet of code, located in the function "compare_voice_list_write_list", start in the line number 79:

```
for ii in list_compare:
    # list comprehension for compare
    comparation = [item for item in list_voice if item in list_compare]
    if len(comparation) > 0:
        for item in comparation: color ="white"
    else:
        color="red"
        # to resolve, BOOM!!! Error, my honey!
    label_entry = Label(self.window, text=ii ,background=color)
    label_entry.grid(row=1, column= ii + 1)
```

For download all code, this is the link to the program:
[List_to_numbers_2.0](https://github.com/Marcogb81/listen_to_number/blob/master/listen_to_number_2.py)

Thank you very much for your interest and your time. :-)

Comment: What is the purpose of `ii`? You are basically checking for the intersection between `list_voice` and `list_compare` for each item in `list_compare` - doing the same operation for `len(list_compare)` number of times.

Comment: Hi! 'ii' has the function of put any number of the list in any label generated. Yes, the function verifies the intersection, but if different this intersection put the background (label_entry)in red.

Comment: `for item in comparation: color ="white"` likely isn't doing what you expect. It simply sets the same `color` variable to the same value multiple times. It's not changing the item.. Without knowing that `item` is, it's impossible for us to say how to change the item. It would help if you included a [mcve] in the question. Nobody is going to want to follow a link to another site to see a bunch of code.

Answer (score 0):

After read the explanation of Bryan Oakley about how to present the questions I provide this example:

```
# test_explanation.py
import tkinter
window =tkinter.Tk()


list_voice = [1,2,3] # correct
list_compare=[1,4,3] # incorrect

for i in list_voice:
    label_voice = tkinter.Label(window, text=i)
    label_voice.grid(row=0, column= i )

for ii in list_compare:
    # list for compare
    if ii not in list_voice:
        color ='red'
    else:
        color='grey'

    label_entry = tkinter.Label(window, text=ii ,background=color)
    label_entry.grid(row=1, column= ii )

window.mainloop()
```

The result is basically correct. But I need show the same order the second row like in list. The code can run in Python 3.5. 
Thank you.